# Linq Many to many

Tags: sql, linq

Could anyone please help with the linq for this problem.

Users have a list of Properties and Properties have a list of Users.

I first do a query to get all Properties with a particular CompanyId. This makes a new list which we'll call MyProperties.

**I need to get all Tenants that have a property in the MyProperties list.**

For other reasons, I don't have access to the "PropertiesUsers" Join table.

Sorry if it looks like I haven't thought this through, I've been banging my head all day on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to flatten the hierarchy:

```
var myProperties = dbContext.Properties.Where(property => property.CompanyId = companyId);
var tenants = myProperties.SelectMany(property => property.Tenants);
```

Comment: I have been stuffing around with Join and Intercept ALL day - THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intersect`:

```cs
var myPropertyIds = MyProperties.Select(p => p.PropertyId).ToArray();
var result = Users.Where(u => myPropertyIds.Intersect(
                                 u.Properties.Select(p => p.PropertyId))
                              .Any());
```

If you are sure that the properties in both lists are the same instances you could use

```cs
var result = Users.Where(u => MyProperties.Intersect(
                                 u.Properties)
                              .Any());
```